Не срабатывает плагин в Revit выдает вот такую ошибку!
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GSmartElectro.Helper.CSetGetParams.SetParam(Element ee, String parname_, Double value)
   at GSmartElectro.ModelProvod.CreateProvods(Document doc, Int32 qty, XYZ p1, XYZ p2, Int32 ibeg, Int32 iend, ElementId trayId)
   at GSmartElectro.ModelProvod.CreateProvod3(Document doc, FamilyInstance f1, FamilyInstance f2, Int32 nProvs)
   at GSmartElectro.CListTraces.ProvodaAuto2(DataGridView dataGridView1)
   at GSmartElectro.FormfTraces.buttonWiresAuto_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Могу предоставить DLL файлы используемые этим плагином, не могу понять что не так.
Изначально он должен строить трассы из проводов, автоматически с заданными параметрами, но в чем проблема я не могу понять

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
